# Add one leading zero to all the values in column in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have one table in terdata "ENRL_RPT" 
The first column of this table is "Main" which is basically groupId but datatype is varchar(10) 
Current values for the main columns are like

```
088767
065456
00142Z
```

I want to add leading zero to all of these values so my result will be like

```
0088767
0065456
000142Z
```

I need to do this as I will be joining  this table with another table using this as Fk. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just concatenate '0' and your column value together.

Comment: `SELECT '0' || trim(Main) as main FROM ENRL_RPT;` should do the trick. The `TRIM()` may be unnecessary here, so try it without first. Just depends on your data types and data cleanliness.

Comment: The table whose column has extra zero is main table (production copy), I can not trim or remove zero from that column so only option I have is to add leading zero to "main" column to "ENRL_RPT"  table which was created by me. So In short I want to ALTER table and column to add leading Zeros to al the values.

Comment: You can pad as many zeroes as you wish in a select - size of the storage column does not matter.